# Is it possible to create a software RAID 10 using SAN LUN's presented to server on 4 paths?

Tags: server, filesystem, configuration, raid, performance

Is it possible to create a software RAID 10 using SAN LUN's presented to server on 4 paths?

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 with 64 GB of RAM

Target is to achieve better I/O, storage and network teams have done all that is possible from their end to provide the best I/O's possible.

and I believe if we can do software RAID 10 using SAN LUN's presented on the server with additional SAN LUN's we should be able to achieve better performance.

Answer (score 0):

The direct answer to what you're asking is yes. But, the disks on the SAN can't have any type of hardware RAID. Your RAID controllers have to be able to recognize disks as a JBOD and present them to your host as such. Even then, the answer is more complicated than a hardware RAID 10. You'll probably end up benefiting most from a software RAID6 with double or triple parity disks.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:  Yes you can, but no you shouldn't.

Long answer:  It depends :)

Most SAN LUNs are RAID protected on the storage array.  Check with your storage team.  If your SAN LUNs are *not* RAID protected on the storage array, this answer doesn't apply.

RAID (other than RAID-0 striping, server side) on RAID (storage array side) is never a good thing.

Assuming the LUNs are already RAID protected on the storage array, you will get the best performance by either striping across the LUNs (RAID 0 on the server side) or concatenating them sequentially.

If the LUNs come from different RAID groups or storage pools, striping across the LUNs that come different sources will be faster (independent head seeks).  Stripe size (amount of data per LUN) should be a multiple of the write cache slot size that the storage team should tell you.

If they come from the same RAID group or storage pool, concatenation will be faster (avoids stair-stepping head seeks back and forth). Again, the storage team should tell you which LUNs are carved out of the same source (RAID group/storage pool).

Modern storage arrays can simplify provisioning by growing LUNs on the storage array side.  Server admins just run vgscan to see the expanded space; no adjustments to the multipathing settings required.

Higher performance can be achieved by adding more paths, rebalancing ports or processors, and by migrating the RAID group or storage pool to RAID10 from RAID6.

This only scratches the surface of SAN performance tuning, and most of this is invisible to server admins.

I spent nearly 20 years as a storage engineer for an enterprise storage vendor.  It was my job to fix SAN issues for various customers and their SAN admins or storage teams who bought our SAN arrays.  Based on that experience, it is my *opinion* that you storage team should be dictating how to configure the multipathed LUN.  SAN arrays are a shared resource and should be managed as such, meaning anything that connects to the SAN must follow standards.  The storage team should be publishing a SAN attached server run book for you to follow that covers at least LUN provisioning, multi-path configuration, LUN expansion, expected SAN performance, expectations during a storage array maintenance, and LUN decommissioning.